# How does initilization of parameters in a function defintion happen?

Tags: c++

I wanted to know that : In C++ , at the time of calling a function by passing some arguments whether the initialization of the parameters in the function happens by the assignment operator or not?
For example :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void fun(vector<int>v2){     
   cout<<v2[0];
}

int main(){
   vector<int>v{1,2,3};
   fun(v);
}
```

I want to confirm that at the call of the function, is the parameter in the function(fun) getting initialized as `vector<int>v2 = v;`  or not? I am not asking this question for vectors only but in general i.e for any object(int , char, any user defined object, etc) that might be passed in a function call.

Comment: By the copy constructor. Like `vector<int>v2(v)`.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Unless you ask language-lawyer type questions about a specific version of the C++ standard you don't really need to add those tags, and then only the tag for that specific version.

Comment: Initialisation is initialisation and assignment is assignment. A parameter is initialised, that is, constructed from the argument, not assigned.

Comment: You asked two different questions. In the first paragraph, "whether the initialization of the parameters in the function happens by the assignment operator or not?" the answer is *not*.  In the second paragraph, "is the parameter in the function(fun) getting initialized as vector<int>v2 = v;" the answer is yes. There are no assignment operations in *any* of the posted code, be it in your code body or the snippet `vector<int>v2 = v;`, for *any* objects of *any* kind.

Comment: @WhozCraig " = " is the assignment operator. In the second paragraph, vector<int>v2 = v;   , here v2 is being initialized using the assignment operator, right?

Comment: No. In that context `v2` is copy-constructed. `Type obj1; Type obj2 = obj1;` is not synonymous with `Type obj1; Type obj2; obj2 = obj1;` The former declares two objects, the second copy-constructed from the first. The latter declares two objects (both default constructed), then copy-assigns (e.g. assignment). In short, `=` is not universally "assignment". The context in which it appears is important. And this is *easily* demonstrable with just a dozen or so lines of code.

Comment: @WhozCraig So , while passing arguments to a function , the parameters are initialized using copy constructer  like  Type obj2 = obj1 , where obj1 is the argument and obj2 is the parameter, right ?,

Comment: Yes, it's just not assignment; it's copy-construction. [See example here](https://godbolt.org/z/G11sYa9qo). You'll see the construction activity is identical in the test_copy_ctor and test_copy_ctor_argument operations.

Comment: Note that if the arguments type if `T*`, `T&` or `T&&` then things change.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow can you elaborate?